# CSV renders in Safari view but I want it to download a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, safari, mime-types, fastercsv

I have configured a custom mime type:

```
ActionController::Renderers.add :csv do |csv, options|
  self.content_type ||= Mime::CSV
  self.response_body  = csv.respond_to?(:to_csv) ? csv.to_csv : csv
end
```

and a respond_to block in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { render :csv => csv_code}
  end
```

Using Firefox and Chrome, the .csv renders to a file which is downloaded. Using Safari the .csv is rendered as a view: How can I change this and force it to download as a file?

See a screen shot of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=thefile.csv'    
        render :csv => csv_code
    end
end
```

if this doesn't work, try using

```
send_file "path/to/file.csv", :disposition => "attachment"
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I have this working in an old Rails 2 app is using `send_data` instead of `render` in the controller. E.g.:

```
def csv
  ... # build data
  send_data csv_data_as_string, :filename => "#{filename}.csv", :type => 'text/csv'
end
```